# Cannot load CSS in Spring MVC

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I tried to create simple spring mvc project, but my index.jsp doesn't want to load CSS. I googled this problem and tried a lot of things, but nothing changed.

My WebAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.training.ytaranau"})
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public Order order() {
        return new Order();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Link in index.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/styles.css"/>">
```

[Webapp structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb1ew.png)

Comment: move `style.css` to `/resources/static/style.css`

Comment: it doesn't work.                                                                            
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/static/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: In your jsp, href="style.css"

Comment: It's also doesn't work, like href="<c:url value="/resources/styles.css"/>"

Comment: `style.css` should not be in `webapp/resources/`. There is a `resources` folder above `webapp` move it there

Comment: I moved styles.css under {proj}/src/main/resources, but it didn't help((

Comment: make `static` folder in resource folder and move `style.css` in it and try to access `localhost:8080/style.css`

Comment: nothing changed, localhost:8080/style.css returns 404, and localhost:8080/static/style.css returns the same

Comment: try to comment `addResourceHandlers` function

Comment: I commented addResourcesHandlers, then commented configureDefaultServletHandling, then commented both of them, but css still not working(

Comment: zip your project and upload it to google drive, then attach the link in your post. I am gonna solve your problem.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HDmRjQqrr9pKtn-EAtgK_6aT-yH0NR_w  . Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `WebAppConfig.java`

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>homework15</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/errorPages/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/errorPages/error401.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-web-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I replaced **WebAppConfig.java** with the below file

**/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-web-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.training.ytaranau" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  cache-period="31556926"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

`style.css`, `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `errorPageStyles.css` are present in `/webapp/resources/` directory.

I have made few changes in `error.jsp` to go back to `index.jsp` rather than `../index.jsp`.

There was some problem in `WebAppConfig.java` i don't know what problem but it is solved by `spring-web-config.xml`.

Also, I have commented the class `WebInitializer.java` because there is no need of it.

Here is the updated project:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Keg3tyu1abVb90GLe9tlnFW-1N3xCszn

Answer (score 0):

I have an Angular 2 based application that is packaged within this file structure `backend/target/appname/WEB-INF/classes/static` and here is how I referred to the mapping.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

> What I would suggest is try adding `classpath:` to the location reference.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
}
```

> Recommendations

You should consider using something like [Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git) for version controlling and [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) for backing up your projects. Not something like Google Drive.